# Java Reflection Output

Tags: java, reflection

I was given the following assignment:

> Write a method displayMethodInfo (as a method of a class of your
>   choosing), with the following signature: static void
>   displayMethodInfo(Object obj); The method writes, to the standard
>   output, the type of the methods of obj. Please format the method type
>   according to the example below. Let obj be an instance of the
>   following class:
>
> ```
> class A {
>     void foo(T1, T2) { ... }
>     int bar(T1, T2, T3) { ... }
>     static double doo() { ... }
> }
> ```
>
> The output of displayMethodInfo(obj) should be as follows:
>
> ```
> foo (A, T1, T2) -> void
> bar (A, T1, T2, T3) -> int
> doo () -> double
> ```
>
> As you can see, the receiver type should be the first argument type.
>   Methods declared static do not have a receiver, and should thus not
>   display the class type as the first argument type.

My working code for this assignment is:

```
import java.lang.Class;
import java.lang.reflect.*;

class Main3 {

    public static class A  {
        void foo(int T1, double T2) { }
        int bar(int T1, double T2, char T3) { return 1; }
        static double doo() { return 1; }
    }

    static void displayMethodInfo(Object obj)
    {
        Method methodsList[] = obj.getClass().getDeclaredMethods();
        for (Method y : methodsList)
        {
            System.out.print(y.getName() + "(" + y.getDeclaringClass().getSimpleName());
            Type[] typesList = y.getGenericParameterTypes();
            for (Type z : typesList)
                System.out.print(", " + z.toString());
            System.out.println(") -> " + y.getGenericReturnType().toString());
        }
    }

    public static void main(String args[])
    {
        A a = new A();
        displayMethodInfo(a);
    }
}
```

This works, but my output looks like this:

```
foo(A, int, double) -> void
bar(A, int, double, char) -> int
doo(A) -> double
```

How do I change this to make the output look like what is asked for?

Comment: Why did you decide to declare the parameters of the methods in `A` as `int`, `double` and `char`? Apparently, the `T1`, `T2` and `T3` of the assignment ought to be the *types*, not *names* of the parameters. If you get the prerequisites wrong, it’s no wonder that the result is wrong as well…

Comment: By the way, there is no need to add an `import` for `java.lang.Class`…

Answer (score 1):

If i understand you correctly, your only problem is having the class type as first parameter in the static doo() method.

You may use the [Modifier.isStatic()](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/reflect/Modifier.html#isStatic%28int%29) method to check this:

```
     boolean isStatic = Modifier.isStatic(y.getModifiers());
     System.out.print(y.getName() + "("
                         + (isStatic ? "" : y.getDeclaringClass().getSimpleName()));
```

You'll have to get rid of the additional comma then, but this shouldn't be to hard ;)

Comment: When I try to incorporate this, I receive an error: String cannot be converted to boolean on this line: System.out.print(y.getName() + "(" + (isStatic?"":y.getDeclaringClass().getSimpleName()));

Comment: I forgot 2 brackets - updated my answer with a tested version.